# How to retrieve data from Firebase Realtime database (Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this piece of working code that saves data to Firebase:

```
let locRef = locationRef.childByAutoId()
let locItem = [
    senderId : [
        "location": getLocationID()
    ]
]
```

And I want to retrieve the user's (identified by senderID) "location".

I want to call the data from another function and present it where appropriate, check my comments in the code below:

```
// Retrieve data from firebase here

let message = messages[indexPath.item] // 1

// Call data I have retrieved below with message 
let text = "Sending from: " + // User Location

if message.senderId == senderId { // 2
    return nil
} else { // 3
    return NSAttributedString(string: text)
}
```

What is the syntax that would allow me to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: actually with the code you attached you are not saving the locationId. Also, do you want to retrieve the user location by the user id?

Comment: I didn't show it but I have another line of code where I save the data. Anyways, yes I want to retrieve location by user ID.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds pretty straight forward then.

```
locationRef.child(locItemId).child(senderId).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        let locationId = snapshot.value!["location"] as! String
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: One question...where did you get the (locItemId) from? What if I need to retrieve the data from another method?

Comment: @AhadSheriff you changed your question to another thing totally different. In this case you should open a new one not just edit it the way its convenient for you. Thanks.

Comment: Okay will do, but can you still let me know what locItemId was?

Comment: The `locItemId` is the Id you are generating with `childByAutoId()`. My answer is assuming that you have this structure `/locations/locItemID/senderID` and when querying the data you already have the locItemID